# Is cm7's stable 7.0.3 market limited with apps?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

For some reason, the apps available on the marketplace for my nook is extremely limited. Am I doing something wrong? I have very few apps, and I only have 2 things to select. Top paid and Top Free, both with very few apps.

I think I have the old marketplace installed, though, I downloaded the latest gapps.

Comment: It could be the Nook or the country you live in that is restricted. I wouldn't think CM would be (unless the apps you're looking for are not compatible with 2.3 for some odd reason).

Comment: The reason is because of pixel density. changing it from 161 to 160 works.

Comment: @diesel: If that's the solution then please post it as an Answer and "accept" it. Then it will act as a signpost for future readers who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, this appears to be the answer:

> The reason is because of pixel density. changing it from 161 to 160
>   works. – diesel

This is discussed on the CyanogenMod forums [here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/29589-some-android-apps-not-compatable/) (along with many other threads). It also appears that newer versions of CyanogenMod automatically set the pixel density to 160 for you. Your ROM's density value should be in the `/system/build.prop` file (look for an entry about "LCD density". It can be modified manually or with one of [several apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=lcd%20density&so=1&c=apps).

Answer (score -1):

It should be because google market thinks the apps are not supported by your device. You can go to [Online Android Market](https://market.android.com/) and try installing the app that is not displayed. It should say that your device(Nook) is not supported for that app.